# How do I disable notification balloons completely in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, notifications, notification-area

I am running VM Window XP and notification balloon in the task bar accumulates so much so I want to get rid of it.

I tried setting it "Hide inactive icons" but still getting notification balloon. I set it disabled for each notification but didn't work at all.

I followed official website of [windows support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307729/) but it only disable one notification. I am getting lots of notifications and if I follow official website, I have to disable one by one because it only applies to one particular notification balloon. I also tried [this website](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/disable-notification-balloons-in-xp/) and followed exactly what it says (see screenshot below), but it wasn't effective at all.

Does anyone know how to completely disable notification balloons?

[image: 3]

Comment: Both links point to the same registry edit, and should disable Balloon Tooltips completely and not just a single one.

Comment: what do you mean by "Both links point to the same registry edit"?

Comment: I mean that both refer to the exact same *EnableBalloonTips* DWORD. That is the officially supported method to do this. After running the Fixit or manually editing the registry did you restart? If you did it properly you should *not* be seeing any more Balloon Tooltips.

Comment: I manually edited and restarted it but didn't work. Let me add a picture.

Comment: It's not letting me to add a picture as I have less than 10 point. I am sure I followed correctly what the official method says.. I will post a picture when I earn 10 points.

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PWQVxZ0cEy4/VS8WSxJCl9I/AAAAAAAAACA/nW5vkSH1bS0/w995-h701-no/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-04-16%2Bat%2B10.44.52%2Bam.png

Comment: Follow the above link for the image. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, seems ok (although full path is not visible but I assume you did it correctly). Try running the Fixit as well and rebooting, then post a screenshot of the balloon notifications you still see.

Comment: I ran Fixit and restarted and confirmed correct set up as I did before but still getting notification balloons.

Comment: That's odd. What sort of notifications, i.e. from which programs? Can you post screenshots?

Comment: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-q7lt3ItgXXo/VS89WQnQ-RI/AAAAAAAAACw/tf7nFeLAFxk/w266-h35-no/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-04-16%2Bat%2B2.40.31%2Bpm.png

Comment: It's a generic notification that my company product send. You know one of those toaster notification..

Comment: I see no balloon tooltips in that screenshot, only notification area i.e. tray icons?

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-MCUaBi64q-k/VS8-tBWHeiI/AAAAAAAAADU/72z0PpsKlnU/w426-h237/Screen%2BShot%2B2015-04-16%2Bat%2B2.46.26%2Bpm.png

Comment: Try this link..

Comment: A-ha! That's why I asked for a screenshot. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see:

[image: 1]

That is *not* an XP balloon tooltip, *this* is:

[image: 2]

See the difference? That thing in your screenshot is a custom tooltip created by your company's software, and no doubt the developers didn't bother to heed the global registry setting you set because they rolled their own solution instead of using the proper APIs. Since it's your own company's software, perhaps you can convince them to modify it.

As such there's no generic way to kill these sorts of custom tooltips unless the software itself has an option to turn them off.

Comment: NP, took some time but we finally got it sorted in the end. :)